# What is a short, drug-induced "blackout" experience called?

Tags: consciousness, psychopharmacology, hearing

I know of anecdotal evidence for the following drug-related side-effects:

- It can happen while getting used to a new drug, or when quitting a drug. Probably also some other situations.
- The feeling lasts a split second.
- All hearing disappears when it happens.
- Before and after the hearing disappears, there is some sort of auditory noise that lasts about equally long.
- It will feel like some sort of mental disconnection, as if you passed out for just a split second - except you don't lose physical control.
- It can happen many times every day.
- All cognitive and physical functions seem to work like normal.
- It can happen with different medications, including Effexor/Venlafaxin and 5-htp.

**What can this temporary black-out be? Does it have a scientific name (i.e., is it a known and recognized phenomenon?)**

Comment: I added one of the related medications to the questions. I need to check up on the other one.
Also improved the wording for the duration of the effect.

Comment: You might want to look into absence seizures, which have a similar (although not identical, I think) profile.

Comment: Doesn't look very much like it:
This phenomenon is much shorter and involves no movement while it happens.

Comment: Absence seizures can also be brief (although usually not split second, so you're right there), but they don't generally involve any movement.